# canvg rendering aligned textPath not working

Tags: canvas, svg, rendering, canvg

im trying to create from an generated (with d3js) SVG Object an PNG image using canvg. 
All the paths (there are not in example) are rendered perfectly, but the textPath, that is aligned to a circle path is not shown (s. jsFiddle example).

**Where does it go wrong? How could be the textPath rendered by the canvg properly?**

Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/T3AR4/

Im using that part in SVG to draw the text:

```xml
<def>
<path id="time_path" d="M450 12.5 a437.5 437.5 0 1 1 -1 0"></path>
</def>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="0%">0.00Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="10%">3.50Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="20%">7.00Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="30%">10.50Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="40%">14.00Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="50%">17.50Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="60%">21.00Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="70%">24.50Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="80%">28.00Kb</textPath>
</text>
<text class="time label">
<textPath xlink:href="#time_path" startOffset="90%">31.50Kb</textPath>
</text>
```

Comment: Search for canvg textPath and the first link you get is this: http://code.google.com/p/canvg/issues/detail?id=111

Comment: @RobertLongson: i saw that. But that issue is from 2011. Maybe there is a solution for that now. One possibility would be to convert textPath to a normal path..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily draw text along a path in HTML Canvas because to do so every single text glyph has to be drawn separately.

There are several examples of drawing text along a curve/arc on the web, for example [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-text-along-arc-path/) (JS code copied below for posterity).

But drawing it along any arbitrary path is a much harder question and because it's non-trivial, most SVG-to-canvas libraries never bothered to completely solve it.

---

JS code from the web example in case that site ever goes down:

```
  function drawTextAlongArc(context, str, centerX, centerY, radius, angle) {
    var len = str.length, s;
    context.save();
    context.translate(centerX, centerY);
    context.rotate(-1 * angle / 2);
    context.rotate(-1 * (angle / len) / 2);
    for(var n = 0; n < len; n++) {
      context.rotate(angle / len);
      context.save();
      context.translate(0, -1 * radius);
      s = str[n];
      context.fillText(s, 0, 0);
      context.restore();
    }
    context.restore();
  }
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'), 
    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    centerX = canvas.width / 2,
    centerY = canvas.height - 30,
    angle = Math.PI * 0.8,
    radius = 150;

  context.font = '30pt Calibri';
  context.textAlign = 'center';
  context.fillStyle = 'blue';
  context.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  context.lineWidth = 4;
  drawTextAlongArc(context, 'Text along arc path', centerX, centerY, radius, angle);

  // draw circle underneath text
  context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  context.stroke();
```